# Implementing Newton's method for the Mle of a Logistic Distribution in R

Tags: r, simulation

Consider the logistic density below:

[image]

> Latex: $$ f \left( x; \theta \right) \frac{\exp\left\{- \left( x_i-\theta \right)\right\}}{\left(1+\exp\left\{-\left(x_i-\theta \right) \right\}
>   \right)^2} $$

The corresponding log-likelihood is given by:

[image]

> Latex: $$l \left( \theta \right)= n\theta -n \bar{x}-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}
>   log\left(1+\exp\left\{-\left( x_i -\theta \right) \right\} \right)$$

Unfortunately, the mle for $\theta$, its mean, cannot be obtained in closed form and thus I have to write an algorithm for numerical optimization. I think it is a good idea to use Newton's method looking for a point where $ l \prime \left( \theta \right)=0$

Now, If we are going to use Newton's method, we will be needing the first and second derivatives of the log-likelihood which are given by:

[image]

> Latex: $$l \prime \left( \theta \right)=n-2 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\exp\left\{-
>   \left( x_i-\theta \right)\right\}}{\left(1+\exp\left\{-\left(x_i-\theta \right)
>   \right\} \right)} $$

and

[image]

> Latex: $$ l\prime \prime \left( \theta \right) =-2 \sum_{i=1}^n
>   \frac{\exp\left\{- \left( x_i-\theta \right)\right\}}{\left(1+\exp
>   \left\{-\left(x_i-\theta \right) \right\} \right)^2} $$

Since the logistic distribution resembles the normal one we can start by using the sample mean as our initial guess, $\theta^{(0)}$, and afterwards proceed according to the familiar formula:

[image]

> Latex: $$\theta^{(1)}=\theta^{(0)}- \frac{l^\prime \left( \theta^{(0)}
>   \right)}{l^{\prime \prime} \left( \theta^{(0)} \right) }$$

I am new to R and therefore I would appreciate some help writing the code.

---

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**: I see that some people from the statistics website in all their wisedom decided to migrate this here where my LaTeX code does not show and people are not statisticians to have worked with distributions. Help if you can but I can understand why my thread might seem incomprehnsible.

Comment: @dickoa I know that the algorithm has to keep running until a specified small value. But I do not know how to make it do iterations. I have written down the formulas, in LaTeX that does not show, and I was hoping someone could tell me which commands I need to use.

Comment: I have some class notes on iteratively reweighted least squares: http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/classes/s4c03/notes/week3B.pdf ; http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/classes/s4c03/notes/week4A.pdf  .  The latter gives a minimal IRLS implementation in R.

Comment: Sure you can't just rework your equations into a form that `uniroot` or `optim` could handle?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Could you please tell me how to do that? I'm quite new to your website.

Comment: BTW,  The LaTex code will show up, at least under Chrome, if you add the "MathAnywhere" plug-in.

Comment: The best options here is to go with `optim` or embrace iterative least square (Ben Bolker answer)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I can see it now, it's a miracle! Thank you!

Comment: I appreciate all your help guys but please type your suggestions into answers, comments are somewhat hard to read. Thank you.

Comment: No worries about the migration, this is the right place.  Plenty of people here know about distributions, and it's a better place to get help on R coding.  Speaking of distributions, are you sure your density is right?  Seems to be missing a square in the denominator.

Comment: @Aaron Corrected it, thank you. I'm struggling to make it work still.

Comment: LaTeX tip: $$ is no longer the right way to delimit displayed equations. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath/40531#40531

Comment: I see you're editing your LaTeX; as long as you're doing so, would you make the `-(x_i-\theta)` parts show up properly in the exponent or add parentheses?  I think if you replace `exp{}` with `exp()` that might work, but haven't tested it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you're asking a very specific question here, I'm going to answer the broader one, which is how one might get the MLE by maximizing the likelihood.  In this case, I would simply use R's built-in logistic functions to get the log-likelihood at each point and maximize the sum.  If there's a particular reason why you want to do this more "by hand", please specify what your restrictions are.

Generate some random data with `theta=30`:

```
n <- 1000
theta <- 30
x <- rlogis(n, theta)
```

Optimize the log likelihood:

```
optimize(function(theta) -sum(dlogis(x, location=theta, log=TRUE)), c(-100,100))
## $minimum
## [1] 29.97946
## 
## $objective
## [1] 2024.383
```

Comment: This is a convenient shortcut, thank you very much! This is precisely what I need to know.  If I understood well, by specifying log=TRUE R takes the log of that function?

Comment: Yes, in this case; it returns the log-likelihood instead of the likelihood.  It's not a generic parameter for use in all other functions though.

Comment: May I also ask why you put a minus in front of the sum of the log likelihood?

Comment: Because by default, `optimize` finds a minimum.  You could use `maximum=TRUE` instead.  See `?optimize`.

Answer (score 2):

type `?uniroot` for the help page. Then write your equation so that you have some function like `f(x) = left(x)-right(x)` which you wish to find the root of, i.e. the value of x which sets `f(x)` to zero. Then stuff that function into `uniroot`.

Comment: I have a vector of observations x,n=1000x, n=1000 and I want to find the value of θ that makes the first derivative(please see above) equal to zero. I have tried the command >uniroot(fuction(y) -2*sum(exp(-(x-y))/(1+exp(-(x-y)),lower=-100,upper=100,tol=10^(-8),maxiter=10) but it does not seem to work. The error is Error: unexpected ',' in "uniroot(fuction(y) -2*sum(exp(-(x-y))/(1+exp(-(x-y))," What went wrong?

Comment: @JohnK Typically that suggests a mismatched parenthesis, so a comma shows up in the wrong function.  You **did** spell "function" correctly I hope!